# The function "hog.detectMultiScale(frame)" doesn't return any thing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, vision, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I wrote this and it works. but the last function (hog.detectMultiScale) doesn't return any thing. I don't know why.

'''

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

cv2.startWindowThread()

# open video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("E:\\3.mp4")

# the output will be written to output.avi
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),15.,
    (640, 480))

while (True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # resizing for faster detection
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    returns the bounding boxes for the detected objects
       
    (boxes, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(frame)
```

'''

Comment: define "not anything". show `print(boxes); print(weights)`. why do you expect it to return? **show a picture** that you expect detections for

Comment: I meant "these variables was empty after running and debugging the code". Now I realize that , in some frame, the detection algorithm doesn't detect anything and so the variables keep nothing.